# Solr join query between two document

Tags: solr

I have product document having "sid" field is foreign key for sales document and another document sales it have "id" field this is primary field in sales document. how to get all the products matched sales document having "sid" values in sales document.

how to write solr join query?

Example:
Having solr core name "test" under this we have following data.
"docs": [
      {
        "PPS_productID": "CB_9457",
        "documentType": "Sales",
        "name":"A1"

```
  },
  {
    "documentType": "Products",
    "PPS_productID": "PPS3-639",
    "PPS_storeid": "CB_9457"
  },
  {
    "PPS_productID": "CB_9458",
    "documentType": "Sales",
    "name":"A2"
  },
  {
    "documentType": "Products",
    "PPS_productID": "PPS3-640",
    "PPS_storeid": "CB_9458"
  }
  {
    "PPS_productID": "CB_9459",
    "documentType": "Sales"
    "name":"A3"
  },
  {
    "documentType": "Products",
    "PPS_productID": "PPS3-640",
    "PPS_storeid": "CB_9460"
  }
```

]

How to get the following response from join query. 
"docs": [
      {
        "documentType": "Products",
        "PPS_productID": "PPS3-639",
        "PPS_storeid": "CB_9457",
        "name":"A1"
      },
      {
        "documentType": "Products",
        "PPS_productID": "PPS3-640",
        "PPS_storeid": "CB_9458",
        "name":"A2"
      }
]

Comment: you need to explain more. Are these all documents in the same collection or different collections? If all are in one collection how do you separate them?

Comment: These all under single core with different document type. Product is one document and sales is another document.

Comment: Do you have an example of how these documents look and what you want to achieve? It's hard to tell what you want your query to return from your question.

Comment: Here "test" is collection and we have separated by using documentType. one is product and another one is sales

Comment: You can't fetch data from both sides of the join in regular Solr joins. If that's a necessity, you'll have to look at streaming expressions - which is a fairly new feature to Solr.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this 2 ways. We need two separate entities like table or collection to run join queries and we dont have separate entities. I would say your collection is more convenient. 
Solution -  Suppose sales id is 1234 and type is field to separate document.

1. `q=*:*&fq=sid:1234 OR id:1234`
   In this you will get all qualified documents as normal results and you will have to separate them.
2. `q=*:*&fq=sid:1234 OR id:1234&group=true&group.field=type`
   In this you will get groups with type values.

I would suggest go with first option.